# You think centering a menu navbar is easy?

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to use HTML5 and CSS3. Can't get this menu navbar centered on my hopefully responsive website.

```css
nav ul,
nav ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#mainav,
#breadcrumb,
.sidebar nav {
  line-height: normal;
}

#mainav .drop::after,
#mainav li li .drop::after,
#breadcrumb li a::after,
.sidebar nav a::after {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
}


/* Top Navigation */

#mainav {}

#mainav ul {}

#mainav ul ul {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: left;
}

#mainav ul ul ul {
  left: 160px;
  top: 0;
}

#mainav li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#mainav li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

#mainav li li {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: none;
}

#mainav ul.clear {
  border: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
}

#mainav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#mainav li li a {
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
}

#mainav li li:first-child a,
#mainav li li:last-child a {
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
}

#mainav .drop {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

#mainav li li a,
#mainav li li .drop {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper row2">
  <nav id="mainav" class="hoc clear">
    <ul class="clear">
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="drop" href="#">Search properties</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="search.html">Search properties</a></li>
          <li><a href="tips.html">Tips for parents</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a class="drop" href="#">Owners</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="register.html">Register & FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I've added so much code that the system here is complaining, so I've had to edit the last few lines out.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your HTML has no closing tags and is a list. Your CSS has selectors for level 2 and 3 lists (`ul ul ul`). Also typo in padding which lacks a(n) unit like `px`.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to post info...

Answer (score 0):

Just add this, it centers the `ul` inside the `nav` element:

```
#mainav {
  text-align: center;
}

#mainav ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Plus I swapped an `</li>` with a `</ul>` tag at the end of the submenu - wrong order.

```css
nav ul,
nav ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#mainav,
#breadcrumb,
.sidebar nav {
  line-height: normal;
}

#mainav .drop::after,
#mainav li li .drop::after,
#breadcrumb li a::after,
.sidebar nav a::after {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
}


/* Top Navigation */

#mainav {
text-align: center;
}

#mainav ul {
display: inline-block;
}

#mainav ul ul {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: left;
}

#mainav ul ul ul {
  left: 160px;
  top: 0;
}

#mainav li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#mainav li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

#mainav li li {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: none;
}

#mainav ul.clear {
  border: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
}

#mainav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#mainav li li a {
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
}

#mainav li li:first-child a,
#mainav li li:last-child a {
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
}

#mainav .drop {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

#mainav li li a,
#mainav li li .drop {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper row2">
  <nav id="mainav" class="hoc clear">
    <ul class="clear">
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="drop" href="#">Search properties</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="search.html">Search properties</a></li>
          <li><a href="tips.html">Tips for parents</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a class="drop" href="#">Owners</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="register.html">Register & FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic! That worked perfectly! Thank you so much. also, good spot on the HTML. If I had the budget to hire you full time I would. Don.

Comment: You are welcome! You don't have to hire me, just mark the answer as accepted or/and give it an upvote ;-)